For stair treads, what does "Must be supported full length" mean?
I was working in my basement level on my tri-level home and found that the stair treads are some kind of particle board, and found a sticker that says Stair tread stock for interior carpet application only must be supported full length. What does that mean exactly? These are installed as the main stair treads just like you would use a 2x10 or similar on construction lumber built stairs. The stringers are normal 2x lumber, but the treads and risers are this chipboard material, and there are no extra supporting boards. The treads are 1" thick. Was this built properly? Do they need additional structural support spanning the stringers?

What is the overall width of the stairway and how many stair jacks (stringers) are there?

The stairs are 3 feet wide, and there are 3 stringers, one on each end and one in the center.

The riser board meeting the  tread on the underside is the continuous support.
